# Dimension of vector space (count 0 or not)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Do you count 0 in the dimension of a vector space?

Eg. If $V_\lambda$ is the eigenspace of a certain function $f$, which has eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda$ of $v_1, v_2, v_3$ then the basis of the eigenspace will be

$\{0,v_1, v_2, v_3\}$

Does this have dimension 3 or 4?

Comment: What does $\{0,v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ mean in your opinion? In my notations it is not a vector space.

Comment: ...the basis of the eigenspace will be...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dimension of a finite-dimensional vector space is defined to be the size of any basis of the space. The definition of a basis is a linearly independent spanning set.

If you add $0$ to any list of vectors the list becomes linearly dependent and hence is no longer a basis.

In the case of eigenspaces, which are spanned by eigenvectors, $0$ is not actually an eigenvector and does therefore not belong into the basis. Therefore, if $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are eigenvectors, the dimension of the corresponding eigen space is $3$.

Comment: my notes say that "$V_\lambda$ together with the zero vector forms a subspace of $V$"

Comment: is the zero vector superfluous?

Comment: @1234 Yes, $0$ is always an element of a vector space. But it's not part of any basis and the basis is what is used to defined the dimension of the space.

Comment: @1234 No, the $0$ vector is strictly required by the definition of a vector space. If a space does not contain $0$ then it's not a vector space. But any set of vectors that form a basis for the space cannot contain $0$ otherwise they are not a basis.

Comment: Try to think of different bases of $\mathbb R^3$: there are many different bases, all of which consist of $3$ vectors but none of them contain the zero vector.

Comment: @1234, I think I can clarify what your notes say. My guess is that $V_\lambda$ denotes the set of all _nonzero_ eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$ (in most definitions of eigenvector, the zero vector does not count as an eigenvector). Thus $V_\lambda$ is not quite a subspace on its own, since it does not contain zero. If we throw in the zero vector, then we get a subspace. (Note that many people would just abuse notation and refer to the subspace, including zero, as $V_\lambda$.) But as discussed above, the zero vector never appears in a basis.